# Why isn't this Elenco circuit working in Falstad's simulator?

Tags: simulation, falstad

I'm learning electronics engineering with the Elenco 130-in-1 kit, and I'm trying to get better at visualizing how these circuits are working by making them in the Falstad simulator, but the first one I'm trying isn't working.  Any ideas why not?

[Here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+1+5.0E-6+20.712724888983452+70+5.0+43%0Av+224+400+224+288+0+0+40.0+3.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ar+224+400+48+400+0+100000.0%0Ar+192+272+48+272+0+100.0%0Aw+48+400+48+272+0%0Aw+48+272+48+144+0%0Ac+48+144+224+144+0+9.999999999999999E-5+2.496784919750069%0A169+448+208+352+208+0+4.0+1.0+1.889476327496789E-23+-3.083237000475508E-20+3.8489398070521655E-15%0At+192+272+224+272+1+-1+-0.500715795456153+-0.5007182953311595+10000.0%0Ac+224+144+224+256+0+2.0E-8+-2.999997500124994%0Aw+224+400+320+400+0%0Aw+320+400+320+176+0%0Aw+320+176+352+176+0%0Aw+352+144+224+144+0%0Aw+352+208+352+240+0%0Aw+352+240+224+240+0%0A162+448+144+448+208+1+2.1024259+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A)'s a link to the Falstad circuit.

The purpose of the circuit: It's described as an "Electronic Grandfather Clock", which gives a click every second.  I couldn't find a speaker in the Falstad simulator so I used a diode instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a broken connection between the transistor and the transformer where there is a red dot at the transistor collector.  Fixing this connection and then the circuit basically works; however, the timing is a bit off.  The 100uF and 100k resistors will set the time between the "clicks".   When I ran the simulation, the timing was off.  If you've entered the values and rest of the circuit correctly, then perhaps the speaker load is needed to get the timing right.  Try putting an 8 or 4 ohm resistor in to model the speaker.  Since the simulator shows the current flowing, you can tell when there would be a sound by the current flowing through the resistor.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an AC source, and the capacitors block the DC. The current it shows is the only closed path it can follow.